# CSS for Skype scrollbar

Tags: css

I am trying to implement scrollbar designs as we use in SKYPE ie 
1. hidden when not hovered into the div,
2. visible when mouse hovered inside div and
3. increase in width when hover over the scrollbar.

1st and 2nd Points works fine with below CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

    div:hover {
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

But 3rd point doesnt work, I am trying this to [increase scrollbar width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT0IN.png) from 5px to 15px:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
}
```

Here is the required design:
[Scrollbar_Increase_Width.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT0IN.png)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the below code

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {         /* Remove this line */
    width: 5px;               /* Remove this line */
    height: 5px;              /* Remove this line */
}                             /* Remove this line */
```

Use only this

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
}
```